# Bootstrap Card image invisible area after image text

Tags: html, css

in my project I want to have an image in the header with the name above it, this all works too, but I have an "invisible" area below the image, which according to HTML also belongs to the link in which both elements are.

[The Bootstrap Card with image header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbV58.png) , [The Bootstrap Card with image header 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqsNr.png)

I think it's because of the div element with the text, I've already tried some things in CSS, but so far I couldn't remove the invisible part.

How can I solve the problem?

**HTML Code:**

```css
.img-container .img-content-stats {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 55px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 352px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

````html
```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">

      <a class="img-container" href="#">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="../assets/img/maps/oregon.jpg" alt="Oregon">
        <div class='img-content-stats'>
          <h4 style='text-align: center;'>Oregon</h4>
        </div>
      </a>

      <div class="card-body">
        ...
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
````

Comment: can you give .img-container position: relative;

and .img-content-stats position: absolute; bottom: 0;

That will probably fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix it

```
.img-container {
    position: relative;
}
.img-container .img-content-stats {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 352px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must have given someone width and height in you CSS check inspect what was the problem remove junk width and height if you sill in same issue then then you putt your code at here blow link.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your CSS: `h4{margin:0; padding:0;)`